# Get all product options/variants liquid

Tags: shopify, product, liquid, variant

I'm looking for a way to get all product options/variants for an entire site. Is this possible? I wasn't sure if there was a direct way to do this like "collections.all.products.options" or if I'd have to loop through each product and grab its options/variants and put them in an array. If that was the case I'd have to find some way to avoid duplicates I think?

Say for example my products have colours and sizes. I'd like two arrays of these colours and sizes.

Comment: There is the `all_products` variable which contains all the products. But it would be easier to understand what you need if you show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: @FabioFilippi I've got about 600 products to work with so looking for the most efficient solution. `all_products` seems to have a limit of 20 products so I don't think that will work? I was planning on looping through each collection and then looping through each product.variant to build an array of them all

Comment: @DavidFerguson What will you be using the data for? Is it to be used in Liquid or externally?

Comment: @ItsGageH It'll be used for a filtering system, I know shopify has a way to filter products but I'm using Finsweet filter for this site. I'll be populating a dropdown with checkboxes containing each variant so that customers can select and filter all products

Comment: @DavidFerguson Unfortunately I don't have any experience with Finsweet. It looks as tho its part of Webflow? Are you attempting to use Webflow for the Shopify online store?

Comment: @ItsGageH Yea I develop all of my sites in Webflow and then convert them to Shopify themes